# print different column widths in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pretty-print

Im using python 3 here without importing pandas, trying to neat print an output of a list. It must have varying column widths. E.g. max length of word in column +2. I have a neat output thus far but all columns in all rows have the same spacing. spacing = max length of word.

Here is what I have:
the list is read in from a csv and formatted into the below list labelled list.

```
list = [['0', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '11111', 'Pl'], ['1', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '36', 'Crt'],['2', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '5678', 'cl'],['3', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '7', 'St'],['']]

col_width = max(len(word) for row in list for word in row) + 2   # padding of 2

for row in list :

     print "".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)
```

output:

```
0      Name      at      Address      11111      Pl
1      Name      at      Address      36         Crt
2      Name      at      Address      5678       cl
3      Name      at      Address      7          St
```

Preferred output:

```
0. Name   at Address   11111 Pl
1. Name   at Address   36    Crt
2. Name   at Address   5678  cl
3. Name   at Address   7     St
```

I have changed the rows to columns and it still made no difference. My apologies but what am I not understanding here?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using the maximum length of any word in your data instead of maximum length in given column. You need to calculate the max width for each column and use that instead.

In order to do that you can feed the data to [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to get data column by column and store the max width for each column. Then when you're outputting the data just pass respective width to `ljust`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

l = [['0', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '11111', 'Pl'],
     ['1', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '36', 'Crt'],
     ['2', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '5678', 'cl'],
     ['3', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '7', 'St'],['']]

widths = [max(len(s) for s in x) for x in zip_longest(*l, fillvalue='')]

for row in l :
    print("".join(word.ljust(w + 2) for word, w in zip(row, widths)))
```

Output:

```
0  Name  at  Address  11111  Pl
1  Name  at  Address  36     Crt
2  Name  at  Address  5678   cl
3  Name  at  Address  7      St
```

**Update**: Assuming that all the rows have same amount of columns and you want have varied padding you can use `zip` and create a `dict` that overrides the padding for some columns:

```
DEFAULT = 2
l = [['0', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '11111', 'Pl'],
     ['1', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '36', 'Crt'],
     ['2', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '5678', 'cl'],
     ['3', 'Name', 'at', 'Address', '7', 'St']]

padding = {2: 1}
widths = [max(len(s) for s in x) for x in zip(*l)]

for row in l :
    print("".join(word.ljust(w + padding.get(i, DEFAULT))
                  for i, (word, w) in enumerate(zip(row, widths))))
```

Output:

```
0  Name  at Address  11111  Pl
1  Name  at Address  36     Crt
2  Name  at Address  5678   cl
3  Name  at Address  7      St
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining where my logic was going wrong.unfortunately I cant import any libraries have to use standard python functions.

Comment: @TerritoryMan Do you need to have `['']` as final item in the data? In case all the rows in the data have same number of columns you could calculate the widths with `zip`: `[max(len(s) for s in x) for x in zip(*l)]`

Comment: Thank you niemmi really appriciate it, that works perfectly without the last row there. I can just simply replace that last row with "" before I run the column check and that should give me the correct widths instead of 1 right?

Comment: Actually niemmi is there anyway to vary the column widths so between 'at' and 'address' there is a padding of 1 and between 'Address' and '111111' there is a padding of 2

Comment: @TerritoryMan No, you need to remove it from the data while calculating the widths with `zip`. Of course you can generate the widths by some other means but it will require bit more work. If you want to have different padding just add the padding to `widths` and remove the fixed padding from `ljust`.

Comment: Sorry niemmi I have removed the row and the 
widths = [max(len(s) for s in x) for x in zip(*l)] works not a problem but to which part of this do I add the padding.
my apologies for pestering.

Comment: @TerritoryMan Added example on how to customize the padding for some columns.